# how to sql query to get the right values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 24 tables (JanSales13 – DecSales14) with exact the same columns for each month.
I want to be able to join each of these tables dynamically or alternatively. That is to dynamically choose the tables (eg.FebSales13 & JulySales13 OR DecSales13 & AprilSales14 ).
First of all I need to `union` the chosen /selected tables.
After the `union` operator combines these tables, I want to select some columns and then aggregate their transactional data.
The logic: To be able to choose any two tables. The tables should then combine into one. After the `UNION` operator, get record of the union table

That’s what I have so far. A dynamic  union table. The user should be able to  choose any table:

```
CREATE PROC spCombine
   @Table_Name  sysname,
   @Table_Name2  sysname
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT OFF;

DECLARE @Dynamictbl nvarchar(MAX)

SET @Dynamictbl = 
N'SELECT * FROM ' + @Table_Name +
' UNION
SELECT * FROM ' + @Table_Name2

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Dynamictbl

END
```

This roughly query should be executed after the two tables combine

```
    SELECT
 Product, Description,
 Sum(A_Sales ) AS [A_salesFeb],
 Sum(A_Sales ) AS [A_salesMay],
 Sum(A_Sales ) AS [B_salesFeb],
 Sum(A_Sales ) AS [B_salesMay],
 Sum(A_Sales ) AS [C_salesFeb],
 Sum(A_Sales ) AS [C_salesMay],
FROM ……
GROUP BY Product, Description
```

So my expectation is if I execute the store procedure, the below three steps take place

```
EXEC spCombine @Table_Name =’ FebSales13’, @Table_Name2=’ MaySales13’
```

1. Choose any two tables
2. Combine them together
3. Results from main query

Graphical image:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the logic for the calculation of the columns.

Comment: How can Date equal both 02.2011 AND 03.2015?

Comment: Because I want to get the sum value for each TP when 02.2011 and 03.2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation. use `CASE` with `SUM` like this.

```
select  [TP], 
SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '01.02.2011' THEN Amount1 END) as Amount1_02,
SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '01.03.2011' THEN Amount1 END) as Amount1_03,
SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '01.02.2011' THEN Amount2 END) as Amount2_02,
SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '01.03.2011' THEN Amount2 END) as Amount1_03
FROM [dbo].[tbl1]
WHERE Date = '01.02.2011'
OR Date = '01.02.2011'
GROUP BY [TP]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your `WHERE` clause

```
select  [TP], 
        sum(Amount1) as Amount1_02,
        sum(Amount1) as Amount1_03,
        sum(Amount2) as Amount2_02,
        sum(Amount2) as Amount1_03
 from [dbo].[tbl1]
 where Date = '01.02.2011' 
 OR 
 Date = '01.03.2015'
 group by [TP]
```

Comment: if both `Amount1_02` and `Amount1_03` are `sum(Amount1)`, then the output of these columns should be equal which is not what the expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` to `SUM` correct values:

```
select [TP], 
       sum(case when date = '02.2011' then Amount1 end) as Amount1_02,
       sum(case when date = '03.2011' then Amount1 end) as Amount1_03,
       sum(case when date = '02.2011' then Amount2 end) as Amount2_02,
       sum(case when date = '03.2011' then Amount2 end) as Amount1_03
from [dbo].[tbl1]
where Date = '02.2011' OR Date = '03.2015'
group by [TP]
```

Comment: Hi. It's not grouping the TP instead it is listing them all

Comment: No but I'm getting the whole TP when I do a check by adding for example TP = 'A.1458' to the where clause

Comment: Probably because you need to put parens around the Date = x OR Date = y clause.